# How can i find the Lookup Column id when i pass the data to REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, ajax

As shown in some examples I must use lookup column ID when i pass data to Rest API. But I cannot find what the lookup column's id. So How can i add this id to `data` in rest api?

```
JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FeaturesListItem' }, 
  'SubsystemId':"It will be integer"})
```

[How To insert field of type lookup in the SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267717/how-to-insert-field-of-type-lookup-in-the-sharepoint-list)

Comment: I saw your [other question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/285860/8992) earlier today... when users select the value that you need to translate into a lookup value, presumably they see text, not an integer, and are making their choice based on text.  What field in the lookup list is this text from? The `Title` field?  Or some other field?

Comment: Are you asking for lmy ookup column and its name and subvalues?

Comment: It looks like from your code snippet that the list you are trying to write to is called `Features`, but the lookup column is looking to a different list called `Subsystem`.  I am asking which column from `Subsystem` is what is providing the text that users see when they go to `Features`?  (Even if `Susbsystem` is only the name of the column, but the list it looks at is actually named something different, I think you get the point - what is the column from the _other_ list that provides the text values seen in `Features`?)

Comment: I have a lookup column in the DocumentMeta list. The column name is GecerliUllke . And this column is linked to another list. The name of this list is UlkeList. One column in UlkeList, connects these two lists and that column is called UlkeKod. 
So UlkeKod column connects the two lists. I can see it in DocumentMeta as GecerliUlke: UlkeKod. And it can take multiple variables. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your answers to some of my questions in the comments, here is how you find the correct integer ID to use when trying to set a lookup column using the REST API.

You said that the lookup column you are trying to set *looks at* the list `UlkeList`.  In order to set the lookup column, you need to know the *list item ID* of the specific item you want to link to *in the `UlkeList` list*.  You also say that the values that are shown in the `DocumentMeta` list in the lookup column come from the `UlkeKod` column in the `UlkeList` list.

I am assuming that when users are choosing what value to set, they are choosing from possible values from the `UlkeKod` column. (I am also assuming that these are text values, or something that is readable and meaningful to humans, and not more integers.) So in order to get the list item ID of the item in the `UlkeList` list that has the `UlkeKod` value selected by the user, you would need to send a REST query like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UlkeList')/items?$filter=UlkeKod eq 'Selected UlkeKod value'
```

Presumably you will only get one result for this query, but because of the way the query is constructed you will still get that single result in a `results` array.  So the data returned from that query will look something like this:

```
d: {
    results: [
        {
            "Id": 7,
            "ID": 7,
            "Title": "Whatever the title of that item is",
            "UlkeKod": "Selected UlkeKod value",
            // other columns, such as Created, Modified, etc.
        }
    ]
}
```

This data shows us that (in this pretend example) the item in the `UlkeList` list that has the `UlkeKod` column value of "Selected UlkeKod value" *is the list item with* `ID: 7`.

**That is the integer that you need** to use to set the value of the `GecerliUlke` lookup column in the `DocumentMetaList` list.

So then you would end up doing something like

```
var ulkeListItemId = ulkeListResponse.d.results[0].ID

var data = JSON.stringify({
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.DocumentMetaListItem' },
    'GecerliUlkeId': ulkeListItemId
});

// use that data in your POST to the DocumentMeta list to set the lookup column
```

Now, in your comments you mention "it can take multiple variables".  If what you really mean by that is that the `GecerliUlke` lookup column allows multiple values, then, as is shown in the example in the other question you linked to, you would need to make the `GecerliUlkeId` property in your `data` an object with a `results` property that  is an *array* of all of the list item IDs of the items in the `UlkeList` that you want to set as the lookup values:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.DocumentMetaListItem' },
    'GecerliUlkeId': {
        'results': [
            firstUlkeListItemID,
            secondUlkeListItemID,
            thirdUlkeListItemID
        ]
    }
});
```

If I have made a mistake in that users are not selecting values from the `UlkeKod` column when they are making their selections for what to set in the `GecerliUlke` column, the same general process should apply:

1. Users select the value(s) that somehow indicate what they want to set in the `GecerliUlke` column.
2. You use those selected value(s) to query the `UlkeList` list to get back the matching list item(s).
3. You use the item `ID`(s) in the response from the `Ulkelist` to set the `GecerliUlke` column in the `DocumentMeta` list.

Comment: You saved my life and saved my day !! Thank you so much. You send this answer very clearly. I finished my task  with your support. Thanks! thanks! thanks!